# how to test parametrized unit test case with extra jmockit argument?

Tags: java, junit

I have this unit test code for mocking something:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import mockit.*;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import com.googlecode.zohhak.api.TestWith;
import com.googlecode.zohhak.api.runners.ZohhakRunner;


@RunWith(ZohhakRunner.class)
public class PersonTest{
    @Test
    public void testGetName(@Capturing final Person p) {
        // I need P object for mocking;
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }

    @TestWith({
            "1, 1",
            "2, 2"
    })
    public void test_is_euqal(int input, int expected,  @Capturing final Person p){
        // ... some code here ...
        // I need P Object for mocking but don't want to use it as parametrized 
        Assert.assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(expected), Integer.valueOf(input));
    }
}
```

first test case (`testGetName`) is OK but the second test throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception because I use `@capturing` in the arguments. is there a way to send an argument to a test case and don't `parametrized` it without throwing any `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception?

Comment: You want to user person object optionally in argument?

Comment: @BilalShah yes. but it throws an exception :( because I use 3 arguments in definition of testcase but define 2 values in `@TestWith({....})` I want a way to use `Person` object in arguments that don't throws an exception (like first test case)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You can't do that.

Longer answer:

In fact you try to automatically combine 2 different runners which, in general, is not possible in junit. The easiest workarounds I can think of is:

- creating mocks inside test method manually without `@Capturing` annotation
- using `@Capturing` on fields rather then on parameters (I know, it can get messy)
- combination of the two above

Comment: Please, take the few extra seconds to include proper capitalization and punctuation in your posts.

Answer (score 0):

Using AssertJ's SoftAssertions you emulate parameters in a single test:

```
    @Tested
    private Foo foo;

    @Mocked
    private Baz baz;

    @Test
    public void givenFoo_WhenGetBar_ShouldBeExpected() throws Exception {

        List<Parameters> parametersList = asList(
                new Parameters(param1, expecte1),
                new Parameters(param2, expected2),
                new Parameters(param3, expeted3));

        // For each parameter set expectations and get actual
        // needs to be in for loop instead of forEach if exceptions are checked
        for (final Parameters parameters : parametersList) { 

            new Expectations() {{
                baz.get();
                result = parameters.param;
            }};

            parameters.actual = foo.getBar();
        }

        // This will give a test case name and assert on each item even if another item fails
        // the same functionality of parameterized tests but in a single Test
        assertSoftly(softly -> parametersList
                .forEach(parameters -> softly.assertThat(parameters.actual) // doesn't short circuit
                        .as(parameters.toString()) // test case name
                        .isEqualTo(parameters.expected)));

    }

  private class Parameters {
      Parameters(ParamType param, ExpectedType expected){
          this.param = param;
          this.expected = expected;
      }
      private final ParamType param;
      private final ExpectedType expected;
      private ActualType actual;

      @Override
      public String toString(){
          return String.format("param: %s expected: %s",param,expected);
      }
  }
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
public void test_is_euqal(int input, int expected,  Person p=null)
```